# Debugging python app inside a docker container using VS Code

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug my Python file in a docker container. I am using VS Code server for remote development and I have Docker plugin installed. I created `task.json` and `Launch.json` using `Docker: Initialize for Docker debugging` command. But now when I click on run (F5) I get this error:

[image: error]

the path specified here is for an old project which no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the debugpy library.
*Installation:* `pip install debugpy`
*Example Usage:* `python -m debugpy --listen 5678 ./myscript.py` 
So what are those thing;
`--listen` tells the library to listen a port and the `5678` is that port,
`myscript.py` is the python file of course.

See: [Debugging Python in VsCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)
See: [The Debugpy Package Github Page](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/)
See: [Debug Python Within a Container (VsCode Docs.)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python)

Comment: You are not answering the question I have! I need to debug containers in a VM and currently I am getting this error!

Comment: As you can see, it says that it could not find a folder or file. However, as you concealed the full path, I cannot understand what it is related with. So, please make your question clear.